# Как удалить объект из памяти?

Tags: android, объекты, java

Есть статическая ссылка на класс (объект) `UserInterface`

```
public static UserInterface user;
```

После закрытия в данном случае Android приложения (onDestroy метод) ссылка сохранилась в памяти как собственно и объект, из за этого в методе onCreate не сработало условие

```
if(user == null)
{
    user = new UserInterface(this, getApplicationInfo());   
    user.setListener(this);
}
```

Как удалить объект из памяти?

На данный момент на уме только поставить `(user = null) в onDestroy;`

Comment: Так и делайте. 

Потом объект (если на него не осталось ссылок из других объектов) будет удален сборщиком мусора).

Comment: @avp должен. По крайней мере, условие выполнится. Сам объект не факт, что будет удалён gc так резво.

Comment: Можно наверняка 

user = null;
System.gc();

Comment: katso не факт вообщето что очиститься.

Comment: Не думаю, что это лучшая практика вызывать мусоросборщик явно, если, конечно объект не кушает сотни МБ или пару ГБ, после обнуления ссылки на который создается еще один (или несколько) подобных по объему объектов, где будет смысл очищать память сразу же после того, как она стала не нужна, чтобы прога не кушала без меры ресурсы.

Comment: А чем обосновано хранение чего либо в static полях? У android есть android.content.Context - почему его не использовать?